# Performent way to order results by aggregation

Tags: neo4j

Suppose we have the classic Movies model where people can watch movies.

```
(u:USER) -[:WATCHED] ->(m:Movie)
```

If I want to find for a given user the users that have watched the most similar movies than him, I would do:

```
match (u:USER{id:"MYUSERID"})-[:WATCHED] ->(m:Movie)
with m
match (m)<-[r:WATCHED]-(o)
with m, count(r) as count, o
order by count
return o limit 10
```

But by doing this I suppose that all the users who watched at least one of the movies of the main user, which means in a DB of 5 million users, if the main user has watched MATRIX, we will have to traverse all the 5 million users, aggregate then sort (supposing that all of them have watched it).

I think this kind of requests would be (very) slow.

Is there a tricky way to do is differently, even by changing the model?

Comment: you can store count in User node, whenever a user watch a movie then set `count=count+1`

Comment: This is not a solution because what I count is NOT the TOTAL number of watched movies byt other users. What I count is the number of watched movies that the main user has already watched